# How to config Postfix and Dovecot to receive mail from external server

Tags: macos, email, postfix, dovecot

I am not being able to receive mails in my local accounts, i can only send mails from multi local accounts to multi external accounts.

Till now after several tests, i notice that when i send mails without SMTP AUTH, i receive an message from my ISP mail server, saying that SMTP AUTH is activated and i must activated to pass through that server. If i try to send mail in the external server between accounts of my domain, i dont receive any mail in my local server. If i try to send mail in my local server between local accounts, i will receive mail locally, it will not pass through my external server as expected.

In my external server, i have cpanel, where i create external email accounts. There i have config email routing for the domain that i just want to use in my local mail server. I have set MX records with a secondary priority (in first i have the domain of my email by default). It is config as auto to deal with mail brought also by default(*). The secondary priority is a link (a subdomain of the email domain) for my static IP. I already search if i had my IP blocked and from a big list i only had 1 blocking me.

I have also configured SPF of my external server to auth sends from my local server.

(*)

- Automatically Detect Configuration : (Local)
- Mail Exchanger local
- Mail Exchanger de backup
- Mail Exchanger remote

Right now i have in my main.cf from local server Postfix this:

http://pastebin.com/NXDXihtf

I have also check my router and pc firewalls and no one is interfering with this server. Local firewall is OFF and i test my pc in the DMZ zone. I was only able to test with telnet the IMAP service through localhost connection, from outside i am unable, i get always a refuse connection.

I think that i have made the correct steps with cpanel, but i dont have a clue on how can i set Postfix and Dovecot to receive mails from my external server. =/

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve this problem just through postfix at my local server and a MX record in my external server pointing to my local server. Dont know yet if is from being using a dynamic IP, because is not blacklisted and i dont know if vodafone is blocking this kind os services (SMTP) for dynamic IP's.

So to solve this problem i have used getmail to reroute mail as workaround through sendmail to postfix, there i can accept mail as a mail client, just through IMAP and POP3, and it can be done with SSL. Then i have created several getmailrc's per user, created a bash script to scan all getmailrc files per user (getmail doesnt allow to add more then a user per getmailrc), and then i had to add that script in crontab to run every 1 min.

I have not mentioned but dont use DMZ in your router to solve this kind of problems because you can expose your server to a lot of dangers. Use DMZ just for testing purposes, like i have made. To accept connections from outside you must use port forwardings to certains ports.

I hope this could help more people.